# Angular cannot navigate to nested non-child component

Tags: angular

This is in Angular 12. I have a payments controller in ClientApp/src/app with (not showing all code)
payments.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { PaymentsComponent } from "./payments.component";

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild([{path: 'payments',component: PaymentsComponent}])],
  declarations: [PaymentsComponent]
})
export class PaymentsModule {}
```

and payments.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-payments',
  templateUrl: './payments.html'
})
export class PaymentsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(...) { ... }

  ngOnInit(): void {...    });
  }
}
```

PaymentsModule is only referenced in app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
...
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRouterModule } from './app-router.module';
import { PaymentsModule } from "./payments/payments.module";
....

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    PaymentsModule,
    AppRouterModule,
    .....
  ],
  ...
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],

})
export class AppModule {}
```

There is no reference to PaymentsComponent in app-router.module.ts. File app.component.html has an `<app-menu>` selector, and that selector contains a mat-menu-item which has no problem navigating to Payments:

```
<button mat-menu-item [routerLink]="['/payments']">Payments</button>
```

I want to place a process-payment component within the payments component, however I do ***not*** want the process-payment component to be a child component of payments. I want to navigate to process-payment directly via another mat-menu-item. The code for process-payment is as basic as what I've shown above for the two payments files, and I added the same references in app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
...
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRouterModule } from './app-router.module';
import { PaymentsModule } from "./payments/payments.module";
import { ProcessPaymentModule } from "./payments/process-payment/process-payment.module"; //added here
....

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    PaymentsModule,
    ProcessPaymentModule, //added here
    AppRouterModule,
    .....
  ],
  ...
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],

})
export class AppModule {}
```

However a new menu item cannot find my new component, I get a 404 Not found error with no details:

```
<button mat-menu-item [routerLink]="['/payment/process-payment']">Process Payment</button>
```

I've tried different paths for routerLink, but always get redirected to my page not found component. Not understanding how/why the new component cannot be found, the process-payment structure and reference is the same as payments. Can anyone help or shed some light as to the problem, other than me as the problem? :) Thanks, BB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying to have nested routes. Basically, you should have a `<router-outlet>` inside `payments.component.ts` and add `children` to your path `payments` in `payments.module.ts`.

`payments.component.html`

```html
<h1>Payments</h1>

<a mat-menu-item [routerLink]="['process-payment']">Process Payment</a>

<!-- Children route will be inserted here -->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

`payments.module.ts`:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: 'payments',
        component: PaymentsComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'process-payment',
            component: ProcessPaymentComponent
          }
        ]
      }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [PaymentsComponent]
})
export class PaymentsModule {}
```

If you want to navigate to process-payment from app-component or elsewhere, the `routerLink` would be `['/payments/process-payment']`

You can find the documentation for nesting routes here: https://angular.io/guide/router#nesting-routes

#### EDIT

If you do not want nested routes and only keep them flat with a single router-outlet, then you just need to add a new route for `ProcessPaymentComponent`.

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: 'payments',
        component: PaymentsComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'payment/process-payment',
        component: ProcessPaymentComponent
      }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [PaymentsComponent]
})
export class PaymentsModule {}
```

Then just link to the page like you tried before:

```html
<button mat-menu-item [routerLink]="['/payment/process-payment']">Process Payment</button>
```

Comment: Yannick, my app.component.html has an <app-menu> selector, the mat-menu-item is in that app-menu.component.html. There is no mat-menu-item in my payments component. So where would <router-outlet> be placed? Also I do not want to relate or nest payments and process payment, I just want process-payment to live in the folder structure of payments. Is that doable?

Comment: I think I misunderstood what you wanted, it's totally doable. I edited my answer, hopefully that's what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Yannick, that did it!!! Don't know how I did not realize that. Thank you very much